# Fan runs for heat but not ac

Tags: hvac

Outdoor unit runs fine I have an american standard the fan inside works with heat on but as soon as you try to switch to ac nothing at control board it just makes a weird noise I replaced both the run and start compasitor and still nothing

Comment: just a guess here, it is the relay on the control board that controls the fan. Take a picture of the schematic and post here so we can help looking for it. The heat mode is a different relay, did you try in Fan ONLY mode ? The Cool mode will trigger a relay that starts the AC outside and the Fan

Comment: Yes the fan runs until the ac kicks in then it instantly shuts off ill grab a pocket in a few https://linksharing.samsungcloud.com/vCDUNqRDaffo

Comment: Visualize punctuation, it would help us understand what you are asking.

Comment: What thermostat do you have ?

Answer (score 1):

In most homes, the furnace is responsible for circulating air. **It does not know the air conditioner exists**.

The furnace provides an **air handling stack** in which many OPTIONAL devices can be placed.  One of them is A/C. Not all houses have it. The furnace does not know if it's there.  **It is not enough to run the A/C outdoor unit. The furnace's blower must also run to circulate the air** or you'll just get a block of ice inside the air handling stack lol.

Your thermostat is connected to the furnace. It is separately also connected to the A/C (often using the furnace as a place to connect the wires).  So when the thermostat "calls for A/C" from the outdoor unit, *it is supposed to* "call for fan" from the furnace.

So you need to figure out if the thermostat isn't asking (connecting Rh to G), if the furnace can't hear due to broken wires, or if the furnace is ignoring the call for fan for some reason.  Like the furnace power being shut off.

Answer (score 0):

The basic operation is:

For the Fan in the heat exchanger (sometimes called the furnace) that blows air through the vents.

The Cooling should not run without Fan !

The Heating should not run without Fan !

Fan will run without cooling or heating ! Fan only mode.

Your Fan runs so it is not the Fan (or capacitors). Your AC runs so it is not the AC (outside).

A cooling command from thermostat will do two things. It will start the AC and the Fan.

Same applies for Heating command.

Put the thermostat in Fan only mode. Does it runs ?

Thermostat are different, it is hard to know what wire is for what without knowing the type. You could run it in manual mode (by bridging) the wires, from Rh, for cooling and for Fan. If it runs it will tell you the fault is in the Thermostat.

When I say bridge I mean, use a short wire and connect the Rh to (usually) Y for cooling, and at same time connect the Rh to (usually) G for Fan. It is only 24 Volt so no harm to you.

**Your Thermostat supposed to do that, but it might be broken**